# ProgressDialog troubles

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-alertdialog

I have button that a user selects and I pop up a AlertDialog to OK or CANCEL operation of replacing some data.  The OK and CANCEL work fine after I figured out its an ASYNCH process.
And I even stop multiple clicks.  However when the user presses OK , I have to save the information out to memory along with a couple of tasks.  The OK process takes about three seconds, which is over the edge of impatient people.  I want to throw up a indeterminate progress bar with message. However my newness to Java and android is getting in the way.
Exactly what is the 'context' in the code below?

```
public void getData(final View v)
{
     if(AlertDialogProcessing==0)
     {   
         final String title="Set Image to Wallpaper";
         final String message="Press OK to set as Wallpaper or CANCEL";
         final String ok="OK";
         final String cancel="CANCEL";
         final AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         try{
              alertbox.setMessage(message);
              alertbox.setTitle(title);
              alertbox.setPositiveButton(ok,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){ 
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                   {  
                        Vibrate(ClickVibrate); 
                        Drawable drawable= getSun(imageSelect);  
                        ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading", "Please wait...", true);   //<<<<<<<<<<ERROR at context
                        AlertDialogProcessing=1;     
                        SaveData(drawable,1);
                        AlertDialogProcessing=0;
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Saved.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
                   } 
              });

              alertbox.setNegativeButton(cancel,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1){
                        AlertDialogProcessing=0; 
                        Vibrate(ClickVibrate); 
                   } 
              });
              //alertbox.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); // maybe a 4.0 problem
              alertbox.show();
        } catch(Exception e){   
              //TODO Handle BadTokenException.    
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onClick()` you are creating a progressDialog and you are performing the `saveData()` activity on the UI thread. What you can do is create an `AsyncTask` in the `OnClick()` and in its `onPreExecute()` show the dialog box, perform the saving action in `doInBackground()` and in `onPostExecute()` dismiss the dialog.

The definition of Context is(as per android developer site):

> Interface to global information about an application environment.
>   This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the
>   Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and
>   classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as
>   launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

Hope the explanation helps.

Comment: Seems Android needs a hypervisor that allows the programmer to dictate

Comment: Seems Android needs a hypervisor that allows the programmer to dictate  the order sometimes. I've done parallel and threaded programming and the asynchronous seems to be a combination of the two and headache of the two also. It turns out that my concern of saving the data with a 3 second penalty is not noticed by the random   people I've handed the pgm to. I'll have to add asynch to my toolbox for downloading files. I've actually found the google android exampleless references less than helpful. Thanks for efforts here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing problems with getting context, you can simply replace ,

```
 ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading", "Please
   wait...", true);
```

with,

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(v.getRootView().getContext(), "Loading", "Please
   wait...", true);
```

Here, v.getRootView().getContext(); refers to the context of View Object passed in the getData() method.

Comment: required setting 'v' to final.

Comment: required setting 'v' to final. The progressDialog never gets displayed because it gets dismissed. So still a problem. The behavior is that the OK stays highlighted (as it saving the data). OK /Cancel Alert disappears, the toast appears saying saving was completed. Still the 3-4 second delay as it hangs on the Ok/Cancel. If i comment out the progressdialog dismiss, it does execute the progressdialog (of course it stays on the waiting to load). So the asynchronousity of it is causing it to be handled after the saving of the data and it is dismissed without ever showing. Any help there?

Answer (score 0):

Here context is the context of your activity calling the progress dialog.So it should be YourActivity.this